# Is the phrase "fill up" in the sentence correct?

Tags: word-choice

> The company has to come up with a new set of guidelines or rules [ to cover / to fill up ] what is not mentioned in the established code of conduct.

Which of the two sounds correct?  I thought about the phrases like "to counteract", "to balance out," and "to deal with" as well.   But I still can't figure out which one is grammatically correct.

Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: Also 'that which is' or 'items' rather than 'what is' in a business context.

Answer (score 5):

**[fill up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fill-up)** does not have any suitable meanings in this context: you might, however, say "to fill the gaps in the existing code of conduct".

**address** and **cover** are both appropriate in this context. **mention** implies that not much detail is provided, whereas **address** and **cover** both suggest a complete solution to a problem: it might be a good idea to use one of these words to replace **mention** as well.

> [mention](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mention) - to speak about something quickly, **giving little detail** or using few words
>
> [address](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/address) - to give attention to or deal with a matter or problem
>
> [cover](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cover) - to deal with or direct attention to something

**[come up with](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/come_up_with)** sounds quite informal, and suggests something that might be temporary or inappropriate. **[devise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/devise)** is more formal, and would suggest that some serious thought has gone into the new guidelines. You could also replace **[established](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/established)** with **[existing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/existing)**.

**[counteract](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counteract)** and **[balance out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/balance-sth-out-up)** suggest that you are adding something that directly opposes something that is already there- a minus to counteract a plus. In this case, you are adding something to fill a whole where there is corrently nothing. You cannot counteract or balance out something that isn't there.

**[deal with](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deal)** is certainly a suitable alternative: as you see, it occurs in the definitions of both **cover** and **address**.

I would therefore modify the sentence to something like one of these:

> The company has to devise a new set of guidelines or rules to address what is not covered by the existing code of conduct.
>
> The company has to devise a new set of guidelines or rules to fill the gaps in the existing code of conduct.
>
> The company has to devise a new set of guidelines or rules to deal with the gaps in the existing code of conduct.

Comment: *Extend the rules to cover..*

Answer (score 4):

"Cover" sounds more natural; you can also use "address what is not mentioned".